# Проблема с Python

Tags: python

Я в Питоне новичок. Пишу бота новостей и не могу догнать, где ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
import json
import requests
import keys
from news_file import get_news_from_keyword, get_news_from_topic

telegram_key = keys.get_telegram_key()
base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/' + str(telegram_key)

while True:
   try:
       offset
   except:
       url = base_url + '/getUpdates'
       res = requests.get(url)

       res = res.text
       res = json.loads(res)['result']

       if res == []:
           continue

       res = res[0]['update_id']
       offset = int(res) + 1

   url = base_url + '/getUpdates' + '?timeout=500&offset=' + str(offset)
   res = requests.get(url)
   if len(json.loads(res.text)['result']) == 0:
       continue

   result = json.loads(res.text)['result'][0]
   text = result['message']['text']

   if text.lower() == 'end':
       break

   if text.lower().startswith('keyword'):
       keyword = text.split(' ')[1:]
       keyword = "%20".join(keyword)
       to_send = get_news_from_keyword(keyword)


   elif text.lower().startswith('topic'):
       topic = text.split(' ')[1:]
       topic = '%20'.join(topic)
       to_send = get_news_from_topic(topic)


   else:
       to_send = '\nПриветствую тебя!\n\n' \
                 'Получить новости по теме :\n' \
                 'Тип "Topic Topic_Name" \n' \
                 'Пример : "Topic Weather" \n\n\n' \
                 'Получить новость по специальному слову\n' \
                 'Тип "keyword key" \n' \
                 'Пример : "Keyword Rain" \n\n\n' \
                 'Если вы не получили новость,\n' \
                 'Попробуйте отправить еще раз с правильным кодом\n\n\n' \
                 'Пожалуйста, подождите хотя бы 5 секунд, чтобы получить ответ\n'

   sender = str(result['message']['from']['id'])

   if type(to_send) == str:
       reply_url = base_url + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(sender) + '&text=' + str(to_send)
       requests.get(reply_url)

   if type(to_send) == list:
       if len(to_send) == 0:
           header = 'Не найдена новость :' + str(text) + '\nПерефразируйте это.'
           reply_url = base_url + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(sender) + '&text=' + str(header)
           requests.get(reply_url)
           requests.get(reply_url)

       else:
           header = 'Top ' + str(len(to_send)) + ' Результат для вас'
           reply_url = base_url + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(sender) + '&text=' + str(header)
           requests.get(reply_url)

           for reply in to_send:
               reply_url = base_url + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(sender) + '&text=' + str(reply)
               requests.get(reply_url)

   offset += 1
```

Выдаёт две ошибки.

line 11, in 
offset
NameError: name 'offset' is not defined

line 17, in 
res = json.loads(res)['result']
KeyError: 'result'

Comment: Что тут догонять? В тексте ошибки прямо указано, где она.

Answer (score 0):

Могу подсказать лишь на счет первой ошибки: offset не существует на момент, когда ты пытаешься его вызвать. Его нужно хотя бы пустым объявить перед местом, где ты его вызываешь, чтобы потом в случае исключения у тебя нулевая переменная offset уже заполнилась тем, чем надо